# iOS Unit Testing: XCTestSuite, XCTest, XCTestRun, XCTestCase methods

Tags: unit-testing, ios7, tdd, xcode5

In my daily unit test coding with Xcode, I only use XCTestCase. There are also these other classes that don't seem to get used much such as: XCTestSuite, XCTest, XCTestRun.

What are XCTestSuite, XCTest, XCTestRun for? When do you use them?

Also, XCTestCase header has a few methods such as:

```
defaultTestSuite
invokeTest
testCaseWithInvocation:
testCaseWithSelector:
```

How and when to use the above?

I am having trouble finding documentation on the above XCTest-classes and methods.

Answer (score 6):

Well, this question is pretty good and I just wondering why this question is being ignored.

As the document saying:

> **XCTestCase** is a concrete subclass of XCTest that should be the override point for
>     most developers creating tests for their projects. A test case subclass can have
>     multiple test methods and supports setup and tear down that executes for every test
>     method as well as class level setup and tear down.

On the other hand, this is what **XCTestSuite** defined:

> A concrete subclass of XCTest, XCTestSuite is a **collection** of test cases. Alternatively, a test suite can extract the tests to be run automatically.

Well, with `XCTestSuite`, you can construct your own test suite for specific subset of test cases, instead of the default suite ( `[XCTestCase defaultTestSuite]` ), which as all test cases.

*Actually, the default XCTestSuite is composed of every test case found in the runtime environment - all methods with no parameters, returning no value, and prefixed with ‘test’ in all subclasses of XCTestCase.*

What about the **`XCTestRun`** class?

> A test run collects information about the execution of a test. Failures in explicit
>   test assertions are classified as "expected", while failures from unrelated or
>   uncaught exceptions are classified as "unexpected".

With `XCTestRun`, you can record information likes `startDate`, `totalDuration`, `failureCount` etc when the test is starting, or somethings like `hasSucceeded` when done, and therefore you got the result of running a test. `XCTestRun` gives you controlability to focus what is happening or happened about the test.

Back to `XCTestCase`, you will notice that there are methods named `testCaseWithInvocation:` and `testCaseWithSelector:` if you read source code. *And I recommend you to do for more digging.*

How do they work together ?

I've found that there is an awesome explanation in [Quick's QuickSpec source file](https://github.com/Quick/Quick/blob/master/Sources/Quick/QuickSpec.swift).

> XCTest automatically compiles a list of XCTestCase subclasses included
>    in the test target. It iterates over each class in that list, and creates
>    a new instance of that class for each test method. It then creates an
>    "invocation" to execute that test method. The invocation is an instance of
>    NSInvocation, which represents a single message send in Objective-C.
>    The invocation is set on the XCTestCase instance, and the test is run.

Some links:

http://modocache.io/probing-sentestingkit
https://github.com/Quick/Quick/blob/master/Sources/Quick/QuickSpec.swift
https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xctest?language=objc

Comment: To be honest, you did not add anything valuable here just links to the documentation

Answer (score -3):

Launch your Xcode, and use `cmd + shift + O` to open the quickly open dialog, just type 'XCTest' and you will find some related files, such as XCTest.h, XCTestCase.h ... You need to go inside this file to check out the interfaces they offer.

There is a good website about XCTest: http://iosunittesting.com/xctest-assertions/

Comment: Thanks, that's how I found the classes and methods in my question!